# Pass new parameter to function called in OnItemDataBound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a question regarding the OnItemDataBound event and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Right now I have

and the function definition is:

protected void FillRepeater(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)

What I'd like to do is pass a parameter to the function like this:

But I'm not sure this is possible?
I've edited my function definition to

protected void FillRepeater(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e, int num)

but I'm not sure how to edit the markup to pass the first 2 expected parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the signature of ASP.NET server control event handlers, but I suspect that you're trying to either pass the index of the current item or grab a property off of the current item. Here's a few lines that might help you out if that's your aim:

```
protected void FillRepeater(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // this will get the object that the current repeater item is bound to
    YourItemType item = e.Item.DataItem as YourItemType;

    // this will get the index of the current repeater item
    var collection = repeater.DataSource as List<YourItemType>;
    int itemIndex = collection.IndexOf(e.Item.DataItem as YourItemType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Actually, I wanted to pass some parameter based on the page I have the control on.

The repeater is bound to an XML file, and there may be only a few items from the data source that I want to display on 1 page, and I can match that up directly to an element in the XML file.

Comment: I see, would you be able to just place the page parameter into a HiddenField instead and then just read the value from there? If not we might need a little more of a description as to what your overall goal is.

Comment: I have 4 aspx pages that each have a repeater, and databind to an XML file.  However, I don't actually want to display the full data of that XML file on any one page, just pieces of it.  So on the code behind for each page, in the function that handles the OnItemDataBound event is almost exactly the same, except for these 2 lines:
string sectionText = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem,"section").ToString();

if (sectionText.Equals("EnvironmentalScan")){....}

I thought it would be much better if I created that as a class instead and passed a string parameter instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your last comment makes sense, I can add a hidden label inside my repeater, and in the text for that hidden label pass any parameters i need.

Comment: Cool, yeah thinking about this a bit I think that would be the most straightforward way to go in your case, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `e.Item` to find controls in your repeater. and if needed you can call the parent to get objects just above your repeater.
what i do is put my data i want to pass into hidden fields and retrieve them as so

```
Dim hListID As HiddenField = e.Item.FindControl("hListID")
```